# Comparing two Date objects with Boolean Class method

Tags: java, date, boolean, equals

I am being asked to use the Boolean Class method to compare the year, month, and day of 2 Date objects. I have searched everywhere and can't get more info on how to do this I've always used the equals method in the Date class not the Boolean class. This is what I have so far but it gives me an error message.

```
public Boolean equals(Object obj) {        
    Date otherDate = (Date)obj;    
    return year == otherDate.year && month == otherDate.month && day otherDate.day;    
}
```

This is the error message:

> 'equals(Object)' in 'Date' clashes with 'equals(Object)' in 'java.lang.Object'; attempting to use incompatible return type

Comment: If you want to override the `equals()` method, you need to have a return type of `boolean`. You currently are using the reference wrapper `Boolean`. If you need to use `Boolean`, you'll have to either rename your method or change the method signature.

Comment: And don't forget the `@Override` annotation before the method

Comment: Is that your own homegrown `Date` class or `java.util.Date`? (For real-life code I would suggest avoiding both and using `LocalDate`.)

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure what sense it makes, but unless I have misunderstood, it fulfils your requirements:

```
public class Date {

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int day;

    // Constructor etc.

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {        
        Date otherDate = (Date) obj;    
        return Boolean.logicalAnd(year == otherDate.year, 
                Boolean.logicalAnd(month == otherDate.month, day == otherDate.day));    
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(year, month, day);
    }

}
```

I am using the `Boolean` class method (static method in the `Boolean` class) `logicalAnd` instead of `&&`. Since each argument is evaluated before the method is invoked, this doesn’t short-circuit the evaluation the way `&&` does. Otherwise it gives the same result. Since you have three sub-conditions and the method only takes two arguments, I needed to nest an invocation as one of the arguments in the first invocation.

As has been said in the comments, the method needs to return a primitive `boolean` (small `b`) and should have an `@Override` annotation. Furthermore, when overriding `equals`, it is good style to override `hashCode` too and make sure that equal objects have equal hash codes.

For production code one would use the built-in `LocalDate` and not write one’s own `Date` class. `LocalDate` already overrides `equals` and `hashCode`, and there’s no need for us to worry about how they are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe we can try a different aproach.

**First:**
Method compareDates discard the time by formmating the Date.

```
public class EqualityDates {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        System.out.println(compareDates(10,0,2019).equals(compareDates(1,0,2019)));

    }

    private static Date compareDates(int day, int month, int year)  throws ParseException {
        MyDate myDate = new MyDate();

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        myDate.setMyDate(formatter.parse(formatter.format(cal.getTime())));

        return myDate.getMyDate();
    }

}
```

**And then:** Class MyDate overrides Equals and HashCode to compare Dates.

```
class MyDate {

    Date myDate;

    public Date getMyDate() {
        return myDate;
    }

    public void setMyDate(Date myDate) {
        this.myDate = myDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;

        MyDate otherDate = (MyDate) obj;

        if (myDate == null) {

            if (otherDate.myDate != null) return false;

        } else if (!myDate.equals(otherDate.myDate)) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((myDate == null) ? 0 : myDate.hashCode());

        return result;
    }
}
```

It's just an attemp!

Answer (score -2):

Two date objects can always be compared using their own equals method which uses getTime() in milliseconds and compares it.

```
date1.equals(date2);// returns boolean
```

You can not override equals method of Boolean class as this class is final, so can not be extended.

Comment: Where does anyone mention *overriding the equals method of the Boolean class*? That is not an issue that is in play here. And your answer misses the key problem with the OP's code.

Comment: In the question it is mentioned to use Boolean class equals method which means trying to override that method to use for date comparison

Comment: You misunderstand what is stated in the question. Read the comments to see what the problem really is and its solution. It's much more trivial, one of misuse of wrapper type.